# iptables accept from specific ips slows down SSH and web

Tags: centos, ssh, iptables, firewalld

I used ranges of IP address to block other countries, when I use SSH or some of my web services it slows down, if I remove the rules and put everything back to normal it works normally, any ideas?

Comment: Are you inadvertently blocking your DNS provider(s)?

Comment: Are you taking about a few rules for blocking, or tens of rules, or hundreds/thousands? Please [edit] your question to provide an idea of the scale. Also, are these entries in a single `ipset` definition or are they individual `iptables` entries?

Comment: I basically drop everything, but accept ranges only from my country for specific ports, there are nearly 2500 iptables commands in a bash.
example:
iptables -p INPUT DROP 
and the rest goes like:
iptables -A INPUT -s 2.58.132.0/22 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
for all the ranges which is like 2000 or more.

Comment: Thanks. But please add that to your question. Make it easy for people to find out everything about your question in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Well it's expected to have some degradation, especially if you block ranges of whole countries with iptables. All the rules are being read until there is a match, and netfilter processing could be a pain with lots of rules. If you want to block country networks, use [ipsets](https://ipset.netfilter.org/index.html)

> ipset is an extension to iptables that allows you to create firewall
> rules that match entire "sets" of addresses at once. Unlike normal
> iptables chains, which are stored and traversed linearly, IP sets are
> stored in indexed data structures, making lookups very efficient, even
> when dealing with large sets.